# Windows 2008 Server R2 Recycling Bin too long

Tags: windows-server-2008, process-priority

I get a Recycle Bin as admin in the time when is server not fully loaded.

It contains about 3 mil of files and it takes more than 18 hours to finish.

There will begin a time where is a server fully loaded soon.

I don't want to let a server in production with decreased performance.

Can I stop this operation? what will canceling of bin recycling exactly do?
It is possible to put this process lower priority?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cancel it, the content that did not get to be emptied will still be there.

You should cancel it and use

`del "C:\$Recycle.Bin\*.*" /s /f /q /a`

from an elevated command prompt. Chance drive letter to what you have if it's not C:\ .That will not take up too much resources so you will not notice a performance impact.